# Leaflet 1.7: L.MarkerClusterGroup is not a function

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm trying to use MarkerClusterGroup on a leaflet map. I have the error `L.MarkerClusterGroup is not a function`. I've read the related threads, but they are only valid for versions below leaflet 1.7.

I'm using React with webpack.

```js
import { Icon, Marker, Circle, LatLngBounds, Popup, DivIcon } from "leaflet";
import "leaflet.markercluster";


const divIcon = new DivIcon();
      const markersCluster = L.MarkerClusterGroup({
        chunkedLoading: true,
        iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
          return divIcon({
            html: cluster.getChildCount(),
            className: "mycluster",
            iconSize: null,
          });
        },
});
```

I've also tried to import `L` globally:

```js
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet.markercluster";


const divIcon = new L.DivIcon();
      const markersCluster = L.MarkerClusterGroup({
        chunkedLoading: true,
        iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
          return divIcon({
            html: cluster.getChildCount(),
            className: "mycluster",
            iconSize: null,
          });
        },
});
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you use TypeScript? Is the error in runtime or an IDE (VS Code?) static check?

Comment: The error appears at runtime. No Typescript issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your build engine, the imported `L` namespace from "leaflet" may not be augmented with `MarkerClusterGroup` (from leaflet.markercluster plugin) unfortunately.

But you can resort to using `window.L` instead, which **is** always augmented by the plugin.

BTW, either use the class constructor form with `new` keyword: `new window.L.MarkerClusterGroup()`, or use the factory form with lowerCamelCase: `L.markerClusterGroup()`

```js
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet.markercluster";

console.log(window.L === L); // false...

const divIcon = new L.DivIcon();
      const markersCluster = new window.L.MarkerClusterGroup({ // Use window.L for plugins
        chunkedLoading: true,
        iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
          return divIcon({
            html: cluster.getChildCount(),
            className: "mycluster",
            iconSize: null,
          });
        },
});
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ojki89?file=index.js

Comment: Thanks, it works with new window.L.MarkerCluster. I still have an issue with divIcon, but  Icon will make the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This error raised on my app after upgrade leaflet version to 1.9.1 from 1.8.0

Window.L.markerClusterGroup() instead of L.markerClusterGroup() works for me.

Answer (score 0):

people running into the same issue and using typescript try adding:

```
 npm i @types/leaflet.markercluster or yarn add -D  @types/leaflet.markercluster
```

No need to write any code.

Sourece form [github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/982#issuecomment-1128638027)