# React-leaflet Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'marker')

Tags: javascript, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet and I have created a map in which I have already put markers. And I'm just trying to make a function that when the button is clicked, adds a new marker. But I'm getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'marker')

Note:
The filterGare1 part and the gare variables correspond to longitude and latitude data retrieved from a JSON file

Here my code:

```
import "./App.css";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import { iconPerso } from "./iconMarker";
import { map, L} from "leaflet";
import dataGares from "./data/referentiel-gares-voyageurs.json";


const center = [46.227638, 2.213749];

const filterGare1 = dataGares.filter(
  (gare) => gare.fields.segmentdrg_libelle === "a"
);



function getLayers(){
  var newMarker = new L.marker([42.5020902, 2.1131379])
  .addTo(map)
  .bindPopup("MARKER TEST");

}

export default function App() {
  const [, updateState] = React.useState();
  const forceUpdate = React.useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);

  let niveau = filterGare1;

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={center}
      zoom={6}
      style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=F4ZxF5g8ioWE3GlTx3i0#-0.2/0.00000/76.51878"
        attribution='<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
      />

      {niveau.map((gare) => (
        <Marker
          key={gare.recordid}
          position={[
            gare.fields.latitude_entreeprincipale_wgs84,
            gare.fields.longitude_entreeprincipale_wgs84,
          ]}
          icon={iconPerso}
        >
          <Popup>
            <h3> {"Name : " + gare.fields.gare_alias_libelle_noncontraint} </h3>
            <button onClick={getLayers}>get Layers</button>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      ))}

      <GetZoom />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

I searched for an answer online but none of the proposed solutions solved my problem.
Some talk about markerCluster -> [Leaflet 1.7: L.MarkerClusterGroup is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564694/leaflet-1-7-l-markerclustergroup-is-not-a-function)
But that doesn't really correspond to what I'm trying to do. I only want to add one marker to my map but I dont't know where my mistake could be, can anyone see it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the import of L, this is how I am able to use L

```js
import L, { LeafletMouseEventHandlerFn } from "leaflet";
```

However you mix leaflet and react-leaflet workflows for marker. I would advise you to just use the react-leaflet tag  for all your markers.

Simply add the marker to a state on click and render that state the same way you do with your other markers

```js
export default function App() {
  const [, updateState] = React.useState();
  const forceUpdate = React.useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);

  const [markers, setMarkers] = React.useState([]);
  let niveau = filterGare1;

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={center}
      zoom={6}
      style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=F4ZxF5g8ioWE3GlTx3i0#-0.2/0.00000/76.51878"
        attribution='<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
      />

      {niveau.map((gare) => (
        <Marker
          key={gare.recordid}
          position={[
            gare.fields.latitude_entreeprincipale_wgs84,
            gare.fields.longitude_entreeprincipale_wgs84,
          ]}
          icon={iconPerso}
        >
          <Popup>
            <h3> {"Name : " + gare.fields.gare_alias_libelle_noncontraint} </h3>
            <button onClick={() => setMarkers([[42.5020902, 2.1131379]])}>
              get Layers
            </button>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      ))}
      {markers.map((marker, i) => (
        <Marker key={`marker-${i}`} position={marker} />
      ))}

      <GetZoom />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Edit: The setMarkers did just add the position and not the position in an array. Which should have resulted in `marker` just being a number and not a position. My example is changed to `setMarkers([[42.5020902, 2.1131379]]`.

You could of course use your own object as the the items in the array, this was just to show with the least needed data (position)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried the changes you suggested and now I have a new type error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')`

Comment: I noticed a error in the setMarkers, which I now changed to `setMarkers([[42.5020902, 2.1131379]]`. Since it is important that they positions of the markers are stored in a array. Since we use map

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the way you created **function getLayers(){...}**.

Change it to a Lambda or Arrow function: **getLayers = () => {...}**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).